# Ajax jquery как принять массив json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Отсылаю на сервер некоторый массив с строками, сначала чтоб проверить пробую вернуть его назад:

```
function funcSuccessKp(data){
        console.log(data);
}
var list = ['542313', '422323'];
$.ajax({
        url: 'example.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {kp_list:list},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: funcSuccessKp
});
```

php:

```
<?
  $kp_list = json_decode($_POST['kp_list']);
  header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
  echo json_encode($kp_list);
?>
```

В консоль всегда выводит null
в чем проблема и как правильно передавать массив назад? (любой, в будущем данные будут обработаны и переведены в другой массив)

Comment: `var_dump($kp_list)` в PHP-скрипте что выводит?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт var_dump($kp_list) не выводит вообще ничего

Comment: ну а что он в таком случае должен вернуть? ищи проблему в передаче данных НА сервер. в первую очередь попробуй убрать круглые скобки из `data: ({kp_list:'list'})`

Comment: хотя в целом как бы.. `'list'` в `data` у тебя вообще строка

Comment: @КапитанФлинт ну да, нашел ошибки, имя переменной в лапки взял нечаянно, скобки тоже убрал, но дальше null

Comment: что теперь выводит `var_dump`?

Comment: @КапитанФлинт абсолютно ничего

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84728/discussion-between---and-shumik-ua).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменную `list` в JavaScript нужно перед передачей преобразовать в JSON при помощи функции `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 2):

Где-то в интернете нашел что массив надо сначала переделать в строку, а потом отправлять:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/adminka/scripts/kp_array.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {kp_list:JSON.stringify(list)}, //вот тут
    dataType: 'json',
    success: funcSuccessKp
});
```

ну и... работает)

Comment: дак я тебе то же самое в чате посоветовал :)

Comment: о, да, вижу) напиши ответ, приму)